stopAtFirstError Validation Pipe is not working as expected in NestJS class-validators
I am trying to change the behavior of the errors in NestJS. Currently when it is encountering an error, it is not just sending that error but it is still continuing the validation and displaying other errors as well. I want to display only one error. I want to change that behavior so that when it encountered first error it has to stop the validation and display that error only.
Here is the code :
main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
    app.useGlobalPipes(
        new ValidationPipe({
            stopAtFirstError: true,
        }),
    );
    app.enableCors();
    const port = configService.get('port');
    await app.listen(port);
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}......`);
}
bootstrap();

user.controller.ts
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}
    
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @Post()
    create(@Body(ValidationPipe) createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
        return this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
    }
}

user.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<User>) {}

    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
        await this.userModel.create(createUserDto);

        return {
            status: 'sucess',
            message: 'Successfully created',
        };
    }
}

create-user.dto.ts
export class CreateUserDto {
    @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'id is required' })
    @IsNumber({}, { message: 'Valid id is required' })
    id: number;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    name: string;

    @IsEnum(['INTERN', 'ENGINEER', 'ADMIN'], {
        message: 'Valid role required',
    })
    role: 'INTERN' | 'ENGINEER' | 'ADMIN';
}

Api response
{
    "message": [
        "Valid id is required",
        "name must be a string"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "statusCode": 400
}

Here in the above response, i only want to show one error message in the "message": ["only one message"] (or like this) "message": "Error message". It has to stop the validation when it encountered the first error. but currently it is not behaving like that. can anyone help.

If you want to change the ValidationPipe default behavior it's best to create a custom validation pipe that works the way you need it to. You can create it like so accroding to NestJS docs:

import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';

@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  async transform(value: any, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metatype)) {
      return value;
    }
    const object = plainToInstance(metatype, value);
    const errors = await validate(object);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw new HttpException({
         status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, 
         // Here you should set the message you want, it could be the first error
         // found by the validator or just another custom error message
         message: errors[0]
        }, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return value;
  }

  private toValidate(metatype: Function): boolean {
    const types: Function[] = [String, Boolean, Number, Array, Object];
    return !types.includes(metatype);
  }
}


Once you customized your pipe you can import it globally like so in your main.ts file

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();


More information on custom validation pipes can be found here:
https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator

will this prevent the validation pipe from continuing the validation after encountering the first error? because this line "message: errors[0]" only displays first error. will it prevent continuing the validation of validation pipe after encountering the first error?
